# How do I Rerun test from perforce swarm api?

Tags: api, testing, perforce, swarm

Swarm's web section has a Rerun test button to do this when I pass a review and want to restart other review tests, but I didn't find a way to do so in swarm's api.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing right now is, `PATCH` method in `swarm api` was used to change the current state of `testruns` to `running`, and then `${swarm_URL}/ API /v10/${id}/testrun/${uuid}`, the combination of `testruns` data obtained by `curl`, was used as parameter to remotely start the construction of `jenkins`.